# left and right container are not being positioned next to the content container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something like this

[Image: How I would like it to look (disregard the white spaces in the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nps5K.png)

However, the left and right containers aren't sticking to my content containers. They aren't lining up correctly at the top either. I am fairly confused as to why. I've set my floats, and my top position but it still doesn't work. I have to keep my `main container` in a relative position.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.left-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0%;
    float: right;
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block-inline;
}

.content-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    background: red;
    display: block-inline;
}

.right-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0%;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    background-color: purple;
    display: block-inline;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="left-container">
            <p>This is the left container</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content-container">
            <p>This is the content container</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="right-container">
            <p>This is the right container</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try      display: inline-block;

Comment: @AstroBoyR Just tried, didn't work :L

Comment: Please don't change the original question content, it makes the answers invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 
like using flexbox for this kind of cases:

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}


    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100%;

    }

    .main-container {
        top: 0;
        left:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: green;
        padding: 0;
        display:flex;
        margin:0 auto;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: flex-start;
    }

    .right-container {
        top:0;
        min-width: 10% ;
        background-color: purple;
        height:100%;
 }

    .left-container {
        top: 0;
        min-width: 10%;
        background-color: blue;
        height:100%;
 }

    .content-container {
        top:0;
        background: red;
        width:800px;
        height:100%;
        max-width:80%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="left-container">
            <p>This is the left container</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content-container">
            <p>This is the content container</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="right-container">
            <p>This is the right container</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried setting a max-width and min width for the content container, and the left and right containers stuck to the ends of the screens. How can I make it be stuck to the left and right sides of the content box

Comment: it is still sticking to the ends of the screen rather than sticking to the content-container

Comment: right to make the right and left containers float to the right and left to make it stick to the content container, didn't work. Currently the right and left container is centered between the edge of the screen and the content-container

Comment: not sure how to use the site, but this is what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/Ci0v2dp.png

Comment: Nothing is being displayed in the result area. Maybe jsfiddle?

Comment: I clicked fork and put the css I used. The CTRL + S

Comment: Do you have it in the demo? if not, could you update it so the result is as on the pic? I made the screen larger and narrower on the demo, and it stays the same

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what's wrong. Please explain what's wrong in the demo ? If it's in your code, update the demo. For the moment, demo reflects what is expected

Comment: This is the result: https://js-en6dwc.stackblitz.io/, the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-en6dwc

Answer (score 0):

In this example I've simply floated all the elements to the left; they will float left one after the other in the order that they appear. I've also added a clear float after the main container to restore the normal positioning. I removed all the top and left positioning as these are not necessary to achieve your aim.

I removed the px and just worked with %.

I've added a second example below the first (you'll have to scroll because of the 100% height attribute for the main container) that uses px with max-width and max-height attributes.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container>div {
  float: left;
}

.main-container::after {
  clear: both;
}

.left-container {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content-container {
  width: 80%;
  background: red;
}

.right-container {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: purple;
}

.main-container2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container2>div {
  float: left;
}

.main-container2::after {
  clear: both;
}

.left-container2 {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content-container2 {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 60px;
  background: red;
}

.right-container2 {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 60px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="left-container">
      <p>This is the left container</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-container">
      <p>This is the content container</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right-container">
      <p>This is the right container</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-container2">
    <div class="left-container2">
      <p>max width - left container</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-container2">
      <p>max width - content container</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right-container2">
      <p>max width - right container</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what if I want to set a max-width and max-height for all the css boxes? I tried it, but it messes up.

Comment: I've added a second example below the first that uses px with max-width and max-height attributes.

Comment: This seems to work, but I face an issue where the entire thing isn't horiztonally centered. So I added `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` and made the `width: auto;` of to the main-container2, but it didn't center it

Answer (score 0):

In the old days it was quit hard with mixing with layout, but now when there is Grid is very easy.

Have a look at the example below, i made the layout as grid. 
Click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) to learn more about grid.

```css
.header-container {
  grid-area: header;
   background:red;
}
.content-container {
  grid-area: main;
   background:blue;
}


.left-container {
  grid-area: leftMenu;
  background:green;
}
.right-container {
  grid-area: rightMenu;
  background:#CCC;
}

.footer-container {
  grid-area: footer;
  background:red;
}

.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 400px 400px 20%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header header"
    "leftMenu main main rightMenu"
    "footer footer footer footer";
   
}
```

```html
   <div class="main-container">
        <div class="header-container">
         <p>This is the header container</p>
        </div>
   
        <div class="left-container">
            <p>This is the left container</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content-container">
            <p>This is the content container</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="right-container">
            <p>This is the right container</p>
        </div>
        
         <div class="footer-container">
            <p>This is the footer container</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlexBox for this task. JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gj7a8qvn/4/

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-container {
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1;
}

.content-container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 800px;
}

.right-container {
    background-color: purple;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="left-container">
            <p>This is the left container</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content-container">
            <p>This is the content container</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="right-container">
            <p>This is the right container</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```